# jQuery .each: Do not add comma in last field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get values of all fields in a variable separated by a comma. For example: `1,2,3`

The following code will work fine, but it only adds the comma at end of the last value also. How can I remove that?

```
fields = $('.wrap').find('.text');
var data = '';

fields.each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();  
    if ( value != '' ) {
        data += ' ' + value + ',';
    }   
});

alert(data);
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cn5Gt/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always use arrays for these kind of things:

```
var fields = $('.wrap').find(".text[value!='']");
var data = [];

fields.each(function() {
    data.push($(this).val());
});

alert(data.join(','));
```

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that the , is not required in the join.

Answer (score 3):

You can push elements on array than just use join() method.

```
fields = $('.wrap').find('.text');

var data = [];

fields.each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();  
    if ( value != '' ) {
        data.push(value);
    }   
});

alert(data.join());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below, using the `i` which is the loop index and test against the length of the jQuery object.

```
fields = $('.wrap').find('.text');
var length = fields.length;
var data = '';

fields.each(function(i) {
    var value = $(this).val();  
    if ( value != '' ) {
        if(i === length-1) {  //The last one
            data += ' ' + value;
        } else {
            data += ' ' + value + ',';
        } 
    }   
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn5Gt/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the final character afterwards?

```
data = data.substr(0, data.length - 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cn5Gt/3/

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest of all**:just replace your last line with the below line

```
 alert(data.slice(0,-1));//where data is string
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cn5Gt/7/

DOC MDN : [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var data = $('.wrap').find('.text')
                     .map(function(i,el){ return el.value || null; })
                     .get().join(", ");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cn5Gt/11/

jQuery's [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) will "Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values." You can still include your `if ( value != '' ) {` test in the callback function because if your function returns `null` or `undefined` then `.map()` will not use that particular value. (I've used `|| null` above as a shortcut to an if/else structure.)

Call [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) (or [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/)) on the result and you'll have an actual array, which means you can then use the Array [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to form a string with the values comma separated.

If you need to do other processing on each item besides just getting the value you could stick with the `.each()` loop and add the values to an array that you then join after the loop (like some of the other answers), or just use the string `.slice()` method to remove the trailing comma and space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Using the length function to determine the position of the each

```
    

    var fields = $('.wrap').find('.text');
    var len    = fields.length;

    var data = '';

    fields.each(function(index, element) {

        var value = $(this).val();  
        if ( value != '' ) {
            data += ' ' + value;
            if (index != len - 1) {
                data += ',';
            }
        }

    });

    alert(data);
```